# register post type doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

register post type doesn't work in my wordpress.

Here is all the code.

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( 'Cp_Setup', 'cpActivatePlugin' ) );

class Cp_Setup{
public static function init(){

}
public function cpActivatePlugin(){
    self::_cpCreateCustomPostType();
}
// Registering Custom Post Type if it isn't already registered.
private function _cpCreateCustomPostType(){
    $labels = array(
            'name' => __( 'Custom Posts' ),
            'singular_name' => __( 'Custom Post' ),
            /* etc. */ 
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Page (Custom Post)' )
    );
    $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 15,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
            'has_archive' => false
    );
    register_post_type('cp_custom_post',$args);
}
}
```

But the above code does not registering any post type named "cp_custom_post".

Comment: Does the `_cpCreateCustomPostType` function run? Did you print something to the log to make sure it executes?

Answer (score 0):

`_cpCreateCustomPostType()` needs to run on every request; not just when you activate the plugin. Hook into the init hook, or whichever hook is commonly used register custom post types.